# How do I refer to a distinct number, as opposed to a percentage?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I want to say that we should use a percentage as opposed to a "hard number" (or a distinct value).

Like instead of designating a budget of $990,000 for a particular department, we should designate a budget of 14%. Is there a **single word** to describe this concept?

So can you fill in this sentence?

> "Instead of using a _______ for the budget, we should use a
>   percentage".

Comment: As one who was 40 years a bean counter, I would use *absolute amount*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "absolute amount" or "fixed amount" to contrast with a percentage, which is a "relative amount".

If you only want one word, you can simply say, "Instead of using an **absolute** for the budget, we should use a percentage."

Comment: Thanks for your answer Paul. Is there a single word that can describe the concept?

Comment: @Mike: Try fixedAmount if this is for programming.

Comment: @Robusto, it's not for programming.

Comment: @Mike Sure. You can simply say, "Instead of using an **absolute** for the budget, we should use a percentage."

Answer (score 0):

"definite" as in " definite number"

Comment: "Instead of using a definite for the budget*? What sort of English do you speak?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the word  ***amount***.

> "Instead of using an ***amount*** for the budget, we should
>   use a percentage".

M-W:

> **[amount](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amount)**
>
> *noun*
>
> **1 b** : the quantity at hand or under consideration
>
> What is the amount to be paid?